# Standalone executable

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I have created a python program with gui using tkinter. In the file there are several calls to external text files. I wanted to make a standalone executable using pyinstaller but the executable formed gives an error which is something of the sort "Script cant be executed" ( I don't remember the exact wordings).

How can I take that whole folder and convert it into a single .exe file?

Comment: Run the pyinstaller again and provide the exact error. We cant do anything with "I think this is the error".

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Sorry for long inactivity. @Mike-SMT its hard to put up the exact statement of the error, as the window closes as fast as it opens. Jarad Windows 8.1

Comment: if the message is popping up in command prompt there is likely something you can do to prevent the message from disappearing. Try using [This Method](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000738.htm).

Answer (score 0):

When you build it, you'll either use something like **pyinstaller**, **cx_Freeze**, **p2exe**
and there are many **other**...

You can also refer to this video to understand how and what goes on **[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HosXxXE24hA)**
but basically, with most of these converters, you'll have a `setup.py` **file** that contains information on how to setup your .py and you'll include your **modules** in the packages.

A setup.py file would usually look like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]} 

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "somename",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "this is my software",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        # our package list is included in build options line 3

        executables = [Executable("ourpy_file.py", base=base)])
```

[cx_Freeze Documentation](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html) 
 for more details. If we were to include any other files we would use (with cx_Freeze) `include_files` 
and our `build_exe_options would` look like:

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "tkinter"],"include_files" :"<fullpath>"} 
# this is if we were to include os and tkinter and include some other files
```

Comment: Are there many others? All the Q/A I have seen on this topic only refer to one of the 3 you mentioned.

Comment: cx_Freeze 
pyinstaller
bbfreeze 
py2exe 
Freeze
py2app 
IronPython
portablepython
Cython
Shed Skin
pynsist

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to create a `setup.py` file . It would be better if you pip install `cx_Freezer` than an other library like `py2exe` or `pyinstaller`.

Copy the `DLLs` file from from the directory `\Python\Python36-32\` to the `.py` file directory.

Then you write down the following code :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os.path
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
       base = "Win32GUI"

#os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
#os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35-32\tcl\tk8.6'
import os
includes = os.listdir("") #Include your main python file with its directory

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
setup(name = 'Python_file',
version = "0.1",
description = "Python_file",
options = {'build_exe':{'include_files':includes,'packages':['pygame','tkinter','dill','PIL']}},
executables=[Executable("python_file.py", base= base)])
```

Open `cmd` from the `setup.py` file directory then run `Python setup.py` .

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error

> Failed to execute script ---------- exe name

after compiling with `pyinstaller` make sure you copy all the `files`*(shouldn't be .py file)* you used in script to where you have your `exe` file. This mostly cause by `image files` you used in your program so do well to copy that into the `folder` you have your `standalone file` then start the `exe` file again.

Comment: @Shashank Das make sure you give feedback after following the procedure